# storing multiple AUC's and CI's in R pROC

Tags: r, proc

Is there a way to optimize visualization across multiple AUC's and CI's for different models?

```
roc1 <- roc(outcome ~ variable1)
roc2 <- roc(outcome ~ variable2)
...
ci(roc1)
ci(roc2)
...
```

My goal is to avoid copy pasting across many different models to avoid errors and to have an output/variable like this

```
            AUC       CI
Model 1     0.0       0.0
Model 2     0.0       0.0
..           ..       ..
```

Appreciate guidance,

Answer (score 1):

Create a vector of all the variables (`variable1`, `variable2`) in the example and use `map` function to get the result combined in one dataframe.

```
library(pROC)

n <- 2
vars <- paste0('variable', 1:n)
map_df(mget(vars), function(x) {
  tmp <- roc(mtcars$cyl~x)
  c(auc = auc(tmp), ci = ci(tmp))
}, .id = 'model') -> result

result
```